# Python - pandas to_sql

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

When I change the `Name` argument, e.g. say I set

```
pd.to_sql(name="testTable",constring)
```

the actual table name comes up as `[UserName].[testTable]` rather than just `[testTable]`

Is there a way I can get rid of the `[userName]`? which is linked to the user who runs the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[UserName]` portion of the table name is the `schema` that the table is in. I don't know which database engine you're using, but the schema you're looking for might be "dbo".

According to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), you can provide a `schema` argument:

```
pd.to_sql(name="testTable",constring, schema="dbo")
```

Note that if the schema is left blank, it uses the DB user's default schema (as defined when the user was added to the database), which in your case, appears to be the schema of the user.